# NLog not outputing log file

Tags: xml, nlog

Okay, I'm trying to implement NLog into my project, and I've set a target:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}/Report/log.txt" />
```

This works and outputs the my test logs.  However, if I change `shortdate` to `longdate`:

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${longdate}/Report/log.txt" />
```

Or use the `${time}` attribute, I get no logs.  According to their [documentation](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Layout_renderers), `longdate` and `time` should both be valid.  Am I missing something?  Are they not actually valid for `fileName`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that ${longdate} results in an invalid file name (Windows does not allow ":" as in /logs/01-10-2013 12:24:25.2567/Report/log.txt).

If you add the following to your nlog.config

```
<nlog 
    internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlogproblems.txt"  
    throwExceptions="true"  
    xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

You get a warning to this effect

> 2013-01-10 14:55:21.0436 Error Exception in asynchronous handler NLog.NLogRuntimeException: Exception occurred in NLog ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B)

Edit: added file time example.